# what is the fastest way to initialise a scipy.sparse matrix with numpy.NaN?

Tags: python, scipy

I want to initial a sparse matrix with numpy array. The numpy array contains NaN as zero for my program, the code to initial a sparse matrix as following:

```
a= np.array([[np.NaN,np.NaN,10]])
zero_a= np.array([[0,0,10]])
spr_a = lil_matrix(a)
zero_spr_a = lil_matrix(zero_a)
print repr(spr_a)
print repr(zero_spr_a)
```

the output is

```
1x3 sparse matrix of type 'type 'numpy.float64''
    with 3 stored elements in LInked List format
1x3 sparse matrix of type 'type 'numpy.int64''
    with 1 stored elements in LInked List format
```

for array with 0, there's only 1 element stored in sparse matrix. but there's 3 elements stored in NaN array, how to treat NaN as zero for scipy matrix?

Answer (score 6):

If all you want to do is create a sparse matrix from your data, treating the `NaN`s as if they were zeros, you could do the following. First, lets create a random array with several `np.nan`s in it:

```
>>> nans = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(5,5))
>>> a = np.ones((5,5))
>>> a = np.where(nans, np.nan, a)
>>> a
array([[  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,   1.],
       [ nan,  nan,   1.,   1.,  nan],
       [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  nan],
       [  1.,  nan,   1.,  nan,  nan]])
```

To make this sparse in COO format, it is as easy as:

```
>>> indices = np.nonzero(~np.isnan(a))
>>> sps = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((a[indices], indices), shape=a.shape)
>>> sps
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 14 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

And to check they are the same:

```
>>> sps.toarray()
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Although your `NaN`s are now gone...

Answer (score 2):

The usage of zero as the empty value in sparse matrices is deeply ingrained in the code, so unfortunately it is not very easy to change.

First, I would reconsider the need to treat `NaN` or other value as the empty value in sparse matrices. Perhaps there is another way in your code?

If you really must change the empty value in sparse matrices, then you'll have to define a new class based on [`lil_matrix`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/lil.py) or even on [`spmatrix`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/base.py). Most importantly you need to change the method `get nnz()`, which defines how many points are non-zero. But you also need to redefine the matrix, because as is it is cast as a `np.matrix` of object dtype, and the zeroes are cleared in the process.